# Variational principle with $\delta I \neq 0$

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, definition, variational-principle, classical-field-theory

In [Covariant Phase Space with Boundaries](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.08616) D. Harlow allows boundary terms in the variation of the action. If we have some action $I[\Phi]$ on some spacetime $M$ with boundary $\partial M = \Gamma \cup \Sigma_-\cup \Sigma_+$ where $\Gamma$ is a spatial boundary, $\Sigma_-$ a past boundary and $\Sigma_+$ a future boundary, instead of demanding that $\delta I = 0$, to obtain the classical field configurations $\phi_c$, he demands that $$\delta I=\int_{\Sigma_+}\Psi-\int_{\Sigma_-}\Psi\tag{2.16}.$$

About that he says

> The basic idea of Lagrangian mechanics is that, after imposing appropriate boundary conditions at $\partial M$, we should look for configurations $\phi_c$ about which the action is
>   stationary under arbitrary variations of the dynamical fields which obey those boundary conditions. In fact the truth is slightly more subtle, due to the fundamentally
>   different meaning of boundary conditions at spatial boundaries and boundary conditions at future/past boundaries.  The former are part of the definition of the theory,
>   while the latter specify a state within that theory. If we wish to allow variations that
>   change the state, which indeed we do, then we do not wish to impose any boundary
>   conditions at future/past boundaries. Stationarity of the action under such variations
>   would be too strong of a requirement, typically it would lead to a problem with few or
>   no solutions. The right approach is instead to only require that the action be stationary
>   up to terms which are localized at the future and past boundaries.

Now I admit I'm very confused about this. In Lagrangian mechanics one usually demands that the action be stationary under variations *keeping endpoints fixed*. This condition usually is what drops boundary terms of the form (2.16) in that context and the dynamical problem is always to find paths for which $\delta I = 0$.

When taking a QFT course I have also learned it in this way. In fact, the classical field theory problem is to solve the equations of motion derived out of $\delta I = 0$.

So what is going on in here? Why are we suddenly not anymore considering $\delta I = 0$ and using instead (2.16)? What about all the "variations keeping endpoints fixed" from basic mechanics?

Moreover, (2.16) don't look like we are demanding the action to be stationary, so this seems to change everything about the variational principle.

Why should we demand (2.16) instead of $\delta I =0$? What is really going on in here and how can we properly understand it?

Comment: My guess is that whenever we specify initial conditions on a field, we specify the field for all space, but only at a fixed time. In this sense, I think, the author is saying that the boundary conditions on time will be too restrictive.